# how to obntain google mapAPI Key using SHA1 digest algo on Windows?

Tags: android-mapview

in order to obtain google maps API Key, i am running the keytool command, Java version 7. the command creates a fingerprint in SHA1 digest format by default. when i try to obtain API key by entering this fingerprint (SHA1), i always get an error message from the Google site. The site expects an MD5 format fingerprint. Any workaround possible, guys?

regards,
Kowshik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command:

```
keytool -v -list -alias xxx -keystore xxx
```

This `-v` will show u all three hash code algorithms, such as MD5, SHA1 and SHA256.